# Is it possible to install a PWA directly from the browser and then use NFC on iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, progressive-web-apps, nfc

I'm building a PWA with Flutter and I'm having the following problem:

(iOS only) I want to use the NFC if I installed the PWA from the browser (adding the app to the Home Screen directly). Is it possible to use the NFC doing this?

I know that it's not possible from a browser to use the NFC, but "installing" the PWA like that is there any way to have the NFC rights?

If not, my project wants to detect if two phones are touching, is there any alternative to not use NFC? Keep in mind that I don't want that users install an app.

Comment: Safari iOS doesn't support NFC. See supported platforms (basically Chrome): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_NFC_API.

Comment: I guess Chrome in iOS is not supporting NFC either right? @user18309290

Comment: You are right, it uses WebKit engine.